# EF Core Power Tools - Missing EF Core 5 Version

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET core 5 and entity framework core 5 version in my project and to generate dB Context I am using EF Core Power Tools but the problem is this tool is not showing me EF Core 5 version in the selection. please refer to the below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core 5 is no longer supported. If you really need support and are not able to update to EF Core 6 please contact me via the Github repository and I can provide an unsupported version of the tool that works with EF core 5.

Comment: I've been successfully using EF Core Power Tools in a .NET Framework project referencing EF Core 3.1 but now (presumably after the latest update) I'm getting the error: ".NET 5 and earlier projects are no longer supported". @ErikEJ Can you make it work for my scenario or make an earlier version available?

Comment: @Wazygoose Contact me via Github as I wrote above